# another ListView

Tags: android, listview

i cant display listview from 2 days, read all threads in android.develop, here and in google but i cant figure out what is crashing my app. If i remove last line from ListShow() the app will not crash but if i list.setAdapter(push); the app dont start at all.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Main function
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Call all function to create
    TextCount();
    ListShow();
}

//Menu function
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//Text counter function
public void TextCount() {
    int c=0;
    TextView t = new TextView(this); 
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.file_counter); 
    t.setText((c)+" files loaded");
}

//List Function
public void ListShow() {
    String[] items= new String[] {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4", "item 5",     "item 5"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> push = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, items);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    list.setAdapter(push);
}
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<include layout="@layout/header" />

<View android:id="@+id/separator_up"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@color/blue_light"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="@string/file_counter" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>

<View android:id="@+id/separator_down"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@color/blue_light"/>

<include layout="@layout/footer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/simple"
android:text="" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `ListView` row layout should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/simple"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

it will not work without the layout attributes.

Also, you should always post the stacktrace with the exception from the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You set

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

but your xml file name is "main_activity.xml".

You must set

> setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);